# Deleting a record in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, record, sql-delete

I can't figure this one out. I've look around and here and else where and they all seem to tackle this job in a very round about way. I've created a page for deleting members. The user types in the username, clicks select and that retrieves the specific record from the database. The user can then click the delete button and delete the user. The issue I have is that the delete part doesn't work. Here is the html:

```
<?php
require_once('../include/officer_session_timeout_db.inc.php');
if (isset($_POST['viewmember'])) {
 $username = trim($_POST['username']);
require_once('../include/viewmember.inc.php');
}
?>
```

The part above works fine. It's just the delete section that is not working.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    require_once('../include/deletemember.inc.php');
}
?> 



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
</head>

<body>



<div id="MainContentBox">




   <Div id="MainContentTitle">DELETE A MEMBER!!!!<br>


          <div id="MainContentText">



          <form id="viewmember" method="post" action="">

User Name: <input type="text" name="username" id="username">  
 <input name="viewmember" type="submit" id="viewmember" value="Search">

</form>

<?php echo $firstname;?> <?php echo $lastname;?>        

          <fieldset style="width:500px">
<legend>Address</legend>
<?php echo $address;?><br>
<?php echo $city;?><br>
<?php echo $state;?> , <?php echo $zip;?>

</fieldset>
<fieldset style="width:500px">
<legend>Contact Information</legend>
E-Mail:<a href="mailto:<?php echo $email;?>"><?php echo $email;?></a> <br>
Home Phone: <?php echo $homephone;?><br>
Cell Phone: <?php echo $cellphone;?><br>
</fieldset>

 <?php
if (isset($success)) {
echo "<p>$success</p>";
} elseif (isset($errors) && !empty($errors)) {
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($errors as $error) {
echo "<li>$error</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
}
?>

<form id="delete" method="post" action="">

<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="DELETE MEMBER!!!!">
</form>
         </div>
          </div>

     </body>
```

and here is the code for the deletemember.inc.php file:

```
<?php
require_once('connection.inc.php');
  $conn = dbConnect('write');
    // prepare SQL statement
$sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE username='$username'";
  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  // bind parameters and insert the details into the database
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
  $stmt->execute();
 if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
    $success = "Your information has been updated.";
    } else {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, there was a problem with the database.';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a '?' to mark the parameter to bind. Try this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE username=?";
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
// bind parameters and insert the details into the database
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
```

mysqli needs to know where in the query you want to bind the parameter, so you mark each substitution with a `?`. Check out the bind_param docs for more information and an example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've tried it with the "?" like above, and I've tried it by removing all the $stmt code. I've tried it by using actual data instead of variables, and it never works. It always returns my error that there was trouble with the database.

Comment: Can you update your question with the modified code using the `?` placeholder and describe what error message you're getting?

Comment: It wasn't giving me an error. i think what was happening, was that I was assigning multiple things to the same variable. I reworked it so members aren't really deleted. Instead it changes the the login name. For example, 'username' when "deleted" becomes 'username_deleted' Since members come and go, it would be a pain to add them back. The new username is unknown to the user, so as far as they know, they don't exist. In the process of doing this I basically renamed some variables, and changed 'DELETE to UPDATE and it works now. Thanks again for trying to help this poor newbie out :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where is the param 's'.

The param 's' don't exists, so, you don't need bind them.